# If in one homepage, I click 2 links sequentially in a fast way, what the results will be?

Tags: web, httprequest

If in one homepage, I click 2 links sequentially in a fast way, what the results will be?

I find different homepages process this situation in different ways.

For some websites, if I click link A, then link B in a timely way, the link B will show up. But if I click link B a little slower, then link A will show up.

For some websites, the first link clicked always shows up.

I am new to web. Any explanation and knowledge links would be appreciated.

Comment: This depends on the user agent used as such it isn't really a programming question.

Comment: @PeeHaa, thanks for your comment. I am pretty new to web development. I believe this behavior must be related to some code design, when multiple sequential HTTP requests are sent out, how the server (or even the front end side) determine to discard which request. So I think it is a programming question.